# Unity transform.localPosition , if Parent not in 0 postition that code result is not same as Editor transform positon?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Actually i understand that localPosition means the position of game object "A" (child) inside game object "B" (parent) , when i set "B" the parent to position 0,0,0 and move with mouse my game object A to position 1,0,0 inside game object "B" here if i set with code a spawn position like `transform.localPosition = new Vectore(1,0,0);` and run game ill find it spawning in 1,0,0 the right place but if the parent "B" is not in 0,0,0 ex: 3,0,0 and if i set manually child "A" position to (1,0,0) and run the same code i won't find "A" game object in the same position where it was the 1,0,0 it will be positioned in a weird wrong position , does that means if u wanna use transform.localPosition the parent game object must be at 0,0,0 ?cause i thought we can control a child position in relation to its parent if parent game object is in 0,0,0 or not is not a problem ; 1,0,0 position of the child in editor must be the same if its spawned using that line code `transform.localPosition = new Vector3(1,0,0)?`

Comment: `i set manually child "A" position to (1,0,0)` it is unclear if you mean you set the position using the arrows in the SceneView or by setting the value in the Inspector of the `Transform` component of `A`

Comment: i found the problem , i didn't noticed that i did transform.position not .localPosition in my code

Answer (score 3):

You understand correctly that `LocalPosition` is the position of the child relative to its parent.

If the parent is not at position `[0, 0, 0]`, child transform will be applied first, and parent second.

Imagine the parent is a box and the child is a pencil inside that box. If you move/rotate the pencil, you apply a local transformation. But if you move the box, the pencil will also move.
By the perspective of the box the pencil does not move, therefore it's `LocalPosition` will stay the same. Global position changes for both the box and the pencil, though.

Don't make the box parent of the pencil of you want the pencil to stay in place when the box is moved.

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transform.html) Inspector is the [`transform.localPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html) which is the

> Position of the transform **relative to the parent transform.**
>
> If the transform has no parent, it is the same as `Transform.position`.

So yes if you move `B` and rotate it then the `A` object will be placed to `(1,0,0)` **relative to the parent** → moved +1 unity in `B`'s **local X-Axis**.

In your example if `B` is at `(3,0,0)` then once you enter PlayMode and run the code line `A` will end up at `(3,0,0) + (1,0,0) = (4,0,0)` - assuming `B` is not rotated.

---

If you want a fixed global world position rather use [`transform.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) instead

> The **world space** position of the Transform.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your spawned object at a specific world position and parented by another object, instantiate it first at a world position and then parent it to an object. That way its world position wont change.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class InstantiationExample : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Reference to the Prefab. Drag a Prefab into this field in the Inspector.
    GameObject myPrefab;
    // Reference to the parent GameObject. Drag the GameObject into this field in the Inspector.
    GameObject myParent;

    // This script will simply instantiate the Prefab when the game starts.
    void Start()
    {
        // Instantiate at position (0, 0, 0) and zero rotation.
        GameObject spawn = Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(1, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        spawn.transform.parent = myParent.transform; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lol I didn't pay attention to my code (i wrote it months before) so I fell into this confusion , i did tranform.position = spawnPos not transform.localPosition = spawnPos thats caused the problem i thought it was transform.localPosition . thank you .